# azure what is Time Aggregation Max or AVG

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

I am using SQL Azure SQL Server for my App. My app was in was working perfectly till recently and the MAX dtu usage has been 100% but the AVG DTU usage ois around 50%.

Which value should i monitor to scale the services, MAX or AVG?

Comment: Depends on what you want to focus, having peaks is common for all kind of resources, memory, network, RAM, hard disk usage. The important thing is checking if they are peaks or if the system is too much time at 100% usage. In other enviroments I have said to the client, you have 100% usage alerts, but it is unlikely they will bother you with that, because it was 100% once during a few seconds in a week.

Answer (score 3):

I found on the net after lots of searching:
CPU max/min and average within that 1 minute. As 1 minute (60 seconds) is the finest granularity, if you chose for example max, if the CPU has touched 100% even for 1 second, it will be shown 100% for that entire minute. Perhaps the best is to use the Average. In this case the average CPU utilization from 60 seconds will be shown under that 1 minute metric.

which sorta helped me with what it all meant, but thanks to bradbury9 too for your input.

Comment: None of these metrics matter when talking about *databases*. There are a *lot* of relevant metrics, and a *lot* of them are already monitored by Application Insights and Log Analytics. The CPU won't tell you that a badly written query performs a lot of IO.